# Autoit opens card when it using MouseClick()

Tags: button, browser, autoit, onmouseclick

I have a script where I defined some hotkeys. Each of them should simulate mouse click in defined position (there are push buttons, I define position in INI-file).

I have a problem with one button - usually, when I simulate mouse click by my script everything is OK, but when I want to click on this one button at the same time, when it is pressed, new card is opened in web browser.

When I use my mouse manually and click on this problematic button new card is not opening.

I just cannot find how to solve this problem - I tried find, if it is possibble to lock possibility to open new cards or something like that, but I did not find anything...

All hotkeys I have defined in two vector:

```
Global $HotKeyArrayHotKeys[] = [ "^1", "^2", "^3", "^4",... ]
Global $HotKeyArrayLabels[] = [ "A", "B", "C", "D",... ]
```

Next step is making one vector of structures:

```
For $i = 0 To $MaxInd-1       $HotKeyArray[$i] =
    DllStructCreate($StructHotKey)  
    DllStructSetData (  $HotKeyArray[$i], "HotKey", string($HotKeyArrayHotKeys[$i]))         
    DllStructSetData (  $HotKeyArray[$i], "Label", string($HotKeyArrayLabels[$i]) )    
Next
```

Structure definition:

```
Global Const $StructHotKey = "struct;CHAR HotKey[3];CHAR Label[12];INT X;INT Y;INT CheckBoxNr;INT DataNumber;endstruct"
```

Activating Hotkeys:

```
For $i = 0 To $MaxInd
    HotKeySet( DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[$i], "HotKey" ) )    ;
Next
```

And function opened by them:

```
Func UniversalFunc()
   If @HotKeyPressed == DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[0], "HotKey" ) Then
            MouseClick( "left", DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[0], "X" ), DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[2], "Y" ), 1, 1 )
        Return 0
   EndIf
   For $i = 0 To $MaxInd-1
        If @HotKeyPressed == DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[$i], "HotKey" ) Then
            MouseClick( "left", DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[0], "X" ), DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[2], "Y" ), 1, 1 )
            Sleep(50)
            MouseClick( "left", DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[$i], "X" ), DllStructGetData ( $HotKeyArray[$i], "Y" ), 1, 7 )
            Return 0
        EndIf
   Next
    Return 0
EndFunc
```

X and Y positions are loaded from INI-file.

Comment: Is the control modifier messing things up? When doing your manual test, hold ctrl to see if you get the same results.

Comment: Yea... it is a problem... I see, that only this button has diffrent behaviour when press ctrl...

Thank's for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have determined the Control key down is causing a problem you have two options.

Option #1 Use hotkeys without modifiers. Not ideal.
Option #2 Push the modifier down and up before you force the click.

```
func HotKey()
  send("{CTRLDOWN}")
  send("{CTRLUP}")
  MouseClick( "left" ....
EndFunc
```

The problem with Option #2 is that you have to repress the ctrl key every time you want the hotkey to run.